# Update year and month of date based on select statement

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have table with `columns`

```
Year | Day | CreatedDate.
```

I want to update `CreatedDate column`, so day part like `CreatedDate=Day` and year part in `CreatedDate=Year`.

I tried with datepart function in update statement but wasn't succesful.How can I do it?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if your `Year` and `Day` columns were **computed** based on the `CreatedDate` automatically....

Comment: what will be their month value?

Comment: Your question is unclear, Pls add some data and expected output

Comment: I have data CreatedDate='2008-01-01',Day=12,Year=2012.I want update it so CreatedDate='2012-01-12'

Comment: Is this for SQL-Server? (the `DATEPART()` function suggests it is). And which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE
   YourTable
SET
   CreatedDate = DateAdd(year, [Year] - DatePart(year, CreatedDate), 
      DateAdd(day, [Day] - DatePart(day, CreatedDate), CreatedDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server 2012, that has the new function **[`DATEFROMPARTS()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx)**:

```
UPDATE
   TableX
SET
   CreatedDate = DATEFROMPARTS( [Year], MONTH(CreatedDate), [Day] ) ;
```